# How to generate the layout of an existing webpage?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I recently started working on some wordpress themes.

I usually have to change themes for my clients. Most of the time I need to analyze the theme first. I know that I can use inspecting feature in Google Chrome but I need a designing tool (preferably a chrome extension) that draws the layout of the theme I'm working on (by the main divs).

I need the name of the main divs and their class (or id) on the chart.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to use mozila firefox developer edition. This is the best way to analyze your project

Comment: It would be nice if when recommending anything, you explain how the tool fulfills the request in the question.